# How to use Docker with Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I´m trying to get more familiar with Docker because everyone talks about it and everyone loves it. I know how Docker works in general, but I don´t understand how to used it in practice.

In my case, I have several web applications running on Tomcat. As far as I understand, it´s common to have one Docker container per application. But what does that mean in my case?

Should I have several containers each running Tomcat which in turn runs one web application? Or would I have only one container with Tomcat where all web applications are deployed on?

Comment: I think you should encapsulate each application with tomcat and run it in its own container. It helps the to scale this way taking into account that there are not dependencies between the apps.

Comment: First question is, is it possible for your applications to run on different Tomcats? If the answer is YES. Then run each application in a separate container.

Comment: let's make it simple,
Each container is a process . In your case each web-app is process, so it would not be good idea to hold web-apps under one single docker container. As a container with single tomcat process holding all web-app goes down it will turn off your all applications.
To make it scalable and flexible  I would recommend to have each web-app as single container running with tomcat.
Where tomcat can be your base image to be used by all the web-apps.

Comment: Thanks. Helps me a lot. Some web apps are dependent. But however, If I run each web app in it´s own container, then I would have overhead because each container needs to run Java and Tomcat right?

Comment: Docker containers are built by design to handle and isolate the processes running independently.  There is no as such overhead, as all the work will be consumed by your web-app . Then you run that all together or separately. Also it gives you flexibility to manage each apps  (for e.g. JVM args, ports etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understand why you will dockerise all your applications which are running in single tomcat instances ?**

Lets say if your tomcat goes down then all your application will go down. So 
Docker with microservices is the trend which tells a docker container should not have mutiple applications running i.e single resposibilty model.Avoid one container being responsible for multiple aspects of your overall application.

**What will happen if you put all your applications in single docker ?** 
**Availability** : if container goes down all application will go down. Example : If you have ecommerce application and if offers service goes down then you should be able to do other stuff other that checking offers.

**Deployment** : If you need to deploy an application then all application will go down. for example : if you want to deploy offers update would it be correct to stop all running users which may be doing payments or other stuff?

**Application Load and scaling**  :Lets say you have the modules, Payment, offers and shipping. I would expect the offer module will have more load than all others. So we can horizotal scale the offers service. But if we would have all application in single container then all application will be scaled which waste of resources.

Refer a nicely written nginx tech blog : https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices/

Let me know if you have any questions more to ask. feel free to add comment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is better to run a Tomcat Docker Container for each .war app with filebeat or any other log shipping program in conjunction with single or fewer frontend containers. So 2 Frontend Web Containers for High Availability with 4 Tomcat Containers each serving a Tomcat app.